# how to write an Android app in Java which needs to use a Python library?

Tags: java, android, python

I want to develop an app to track people's Whatsapp last seen and other stuff, and found out that there are APIs out there to deal with it, but the thing is they are writen in python and are normally run in Linux I think

I have Java and Android knowledge but not python, and wonder if there's a way to develop the most of the app in Java and get the info I want via calls using these python APIs, but without having to install a python interpreter or similar on the device, so the final user just has to download and run the Android app as he would do with any other

I want to know if it would be very hard for someone inexperienced as me (this is the 2nd and final year of my developing grade), for it's what I have in mind for the final project, thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running it as one app, what about running the python script as separate from the original script? I believe it would bee possible, as android is in fact a UNIX based OS. Any readers could give their input on this idea an if it would work.